# Python remove all console output

Tags: python, console

I want to erase all console output that was printed before each loop iteration.

Currently I have a code like this:

```
import sys
from time import sleep

def delete_last_printed_lines(n=1):
    CURSOR_UP_ONE = '\x1b[1A'
    ERASE_LINE = '\x1b[2K'

    for _ in range(n):
        sys.stdout.write(CURSOR_UP_ONE)
        sys.stdout.write(ERASE_LINE)

for x in range(1, 3):
    delete_last_printed_lines(3)

    print('')
    print('Some information #{0}'.format(x))
    print('And a lot of different prints')
    sleep(1)
```

But it is working not very well, it "move" console window and remove run command.

Is there is any way to fix it? If it will be Python 3+ only solution it is ok.

Answer (score 1):

You can use subprocess :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
import subprocess
from time import sleep

for x in range(1, 3):
    subprocess.call('clear')
    print('')
    print('Some information #{0}'.format(x))
    print('And a lot of different prints')
    sleep(1)
```

Comment: This didn't anything with console output, at least on Ubuntu 14.04 and Python 3.5

Answer (score 0):

An Unbutu solution would be to call *reset*:

```
for x in range(1, 3):
    subprocess.call('reset')
    print('Some information #{0}'.format(x))
    print('And a lot of different prints')
    sleep(1)
```